# Implementing ASP.NET Core Identity in a n-tier application using EF7 and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, n-tier-architecture

I'm creating an n-tier application in .NET core in which I try to keep the Identity framework out of my presentation layer as much as possible. Since I'm going to use a linux server to run my application, I'll be using Sqlite databases to persist my domain and all identity related classes.
All documentation I've encountered (official ms documentation and various blogs, tutorials ...) doesn't use SQLite.

In my datalayer I have a DbContext class which inherits from the ASP.NET's core IdentityDbContext.

```
public class SquiriusDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HtmlSection> HtmlSections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MediaSection> MediaSections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public SquiriusDbContext() { }

    public SquiriusDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "squiriusdb.db" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }       

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I try to perform a migration, I'm getting  the following error:

```
PM> add-migration identity
An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: GenericArguments[0], 'Squirius.Domain.Authentication.User', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

The error says that the entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined, which is strange since this User class inherits directly from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser.

I think this might have something to do with the limitations of the EF7 Sqlite provider, and using an ms sql server database would solve this error.
Does anyone know a way around this so I can use an Sqlite db in order to be able to build for a linux platform?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a specific problem you run into?

Comment: Yes, I realize now my problem description was not specific enough... I updated my original question.